# Can this extensionmethod be modified to have a cleaner syntax?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

My domain model classes inherit from:

```
BaseModel<T>
```

for example:

```
public partial class WarehouseType : BaseModel<WarehouseType>
{}
```

I am trying to add an extensionmethod to the BaseModel as:

```
public static class BaseModelExtensionMethods
{
    public static TDto ToDto<TDto, TModel>(this Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<TModel> model)
    {
        return Globals.mapper.Map<TDto>(model);
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
Model.Inventory.WarehouseType warehouseType = new Model.Inventory.WarehouseType();

warehouseType.ToDto<V1.Messages.WarehouseTypeDto, Model.Inventory.WarehouseType>();
```

As showen in the above code, I need to pass two types (TDto,TModel) to `ToDto<>` extensionmethod.

I want to know if it is possible to modify the ToDto<> syntaxt in a way that I won't need to pass the `TModel` to `ToDto<>` and get the `TModel` type inside the method for example according to the object type that is calling the extensionmethod? Is there any workaround or magic to do such thing? I need this so that the code will become more clean and easier to use.

The ideal syntaxt I am looking for is as follows:

```
warehouseType.ToDto<V1.Messages.WarehouseTypeDto>();
```

Comment: You could add a dummy parameter to infer the `TDto` type, because you have to infer all types or specify all of them explicitly. `public static TDto ToDto<TDto, TModel>(this Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<TModel> model, TDto dummyToInferType)`  Alternatively you could make `ToDto<TDto>` a method on `BaseModel<TModel>`

Comment: @juharr I can't see how I should call the method you provided. Also It cannot be called like the ideal syntaxt in my question.

Comment: @juharr BaseModel<TModel> is in my domain model layer, and I am trying to extend that inside the ESB layer which is on top of the domain model layer and the Dtos are inside the ESB layer so I can not reference ESB layer from Domain model layer.

Comment: Does it need to be an extension method? Can you just add your method to BaseModel? Can use partial class if you want to put the code in different file.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe It does not have to be an extensionmethod, but I want it to be one. Since the BaseModel  is inside the domain model layer, If I add this method to the BaseModel class, then I will need to inject the IMapper down to the domain model layer and I prefer the currently a little hard to use syntaxt over this DI approach. I know about the partial classes and I have them in the domain model layer, but that is not what I want to do.

Comment: Make sense, I post my code in answer. I'm using mobile, so havent tested the code. But 99% it should work. @Karamafrooz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class BaseModel { }
public class BaseModel<T> : BaseModel { }
```

Then create extension method for BaseModel

```
public static class BaseModelExtensionMethods
{
public static TDto ToDto<TDto>(this Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel model)
{
    return Globals.mapper.Map<TDto>(model);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. It was pretty straightforward and easy to use. :)

Comment: Glad that it helps. :)

Comment: Given that `Map` must take an `object` parameter, couldn't you just have `ToDto` take an `object` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't allow for partial evaluation (or inference) of type parameters for generic types or methods (you could switch to F#, which does). So you have a few choices - you can choose to genericize in steps if you are willing to create an intermediate class to remember the inferred type, or create specializations, or you can infer no types.

To do it in steps, you must break up the `ToDto` method into two parts, and use an intermediate class to carry the inferred type. Call this class `Toer` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345239/2557128)):

```
public class Toer<TModel> {
    Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<TModel> model;

    public Toer(Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<TModel> model) => this.model = model;
    public TDto Dto<TDto>() => Globals.mapper.Map<TDto>(model);
}
```

Now, you create an extension method that returns a `Toer` object:

```
public static Toer<TModel> To<TModel>(this Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<TModel> model) => new Toer<TModel>(model);
```

Now you can replace your old code:

```
var wtDto = warehouseType.ToDto<WarehouseTypeDto, Model.Inventory.WarehouseType>();
```

With the new code:

```
var wtDto = warehouseType.To().Dto<WarehouseTypeDto>();
```

Alternatively, you could create specializations for each possible `TModel`:

```
public static TDto ToDto<TDto>(this Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<Model.Inventory.WarehouseType> model) => Globals.mapper.Map<TDto>(model);
```

which you can use as you desired.

Finally, you could specializations that pre-encode the mapping to the corresponding DTO type, and use those:

```
public static WarehouseTypeDto ToDto(this Model.SharedKernel.BaseModel<Model.Inventory.WarehouseType> model) => Globals.mapper.Map<WarehouseTypeDto>(model);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I learned a lot from your answer and I really appreciate it. But the answer posted by @Alex-TinLe gives me the ideal syntaxt that I am looking for with the least complications and modifications to my code and also without the need to overwork for creating specializations as you mentioned. so I am going to mark his answer as the accepted anaswer.